# AngularJS and a failed templateUrl

Tags: angularjs

Does anyone know how to catch the error in AngularJS when a templateUrl has lead to a 404 error or a 500 error when it's assigned to a route which is directed to a controller? When a failure occurs, I see the issue in my console, but I can't seem to instruct angularJS to deal with gracefully.

Comment: I know it will not help a lot but I would just try to avoid exceptions, must be something weird in the code if you have to deal with this, angular (and js in general) is not really EAFP :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

John Lindquist offers this example (js in [1]) which uses an overarching AppCtrl to listen for $routeChangeError [2]. I assume this will fire for an error loading the templateUrl but I have not tested that. Via [3].

[1] https://github.com/johnlindquist/angular-resolve/blob/master/client/js/app.js#L51

[2] http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$route

[3] https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/angular/KUIVbdlGGbE